# Why dont sephardim like to gladden brides or escort the dead?

Tags: prayer-book

My picture is too large to upload but in this. Mizrachi Siddur Ichveh Daat, the "Eli Devarim" part omits these items which are found in the Ashkenazi version?

I am pretty sure this passage is a mishna. Why the omission?

Comment: אלו הדברים שאין להם שיעור or שאדם אוכל?

Comment: Did you check the Mishna? There must be a reference there

Comment: Many picture editing programs allow you to resize the picture, or you can convert it to another format that's smaller (.tiff, .gif, .png).

Answer (score 5):

First we list off the mitzvot for which there is no set amount, which is Mishna Peah 1:1.

Then we get to a list of mitzvot for which one enjoys the interest in this world: there are several variations on that text in several places of the Talmud; and those places in the Talmud themselves may have variant readings as well. Presumably the siddur you'd seen follows [the continuing text of Mishna Peah 1:1 that Mechon Mamre considers authoritative](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h12.htm):

> ואלו דברים שאדם אוכל מפירותיהן בעולם הזה, והקרן קיימת לו לעולם הבא--כיבוד אב ואם, וגמילות חסדים, והבאת שלום בין אדם לחברו; ותלמוד תורה כנגד כולם.

(The common Ashkanazi longer list appears to be based on a discussion in Bavli Shabbos 127a.)

Comment: Good answer. Is there a reason why different groups choose different versions?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Good question. Why don't you ask it?

Comment: I did. This that question.